# Set of values in pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm writing some pl/pgsql code in postgres - and have come up to this issue.  Simplified, my code looks like this:

```
declare
    resulter     mytype%rowtype;

...

for resulter in
    select id, [a lot of other fields]
    from mytable [joining a lot of other tables]
    where [some reasonable where clause]
loop
    if [certain condition on the resulter] then
        [add id to a set];
    end if;
    return next resulter;
end loop;

select into myvar sum([some field])
from anothertable
where id in ([my set from above])
```

The question is around the [add to set].  In another scenario in the past, I used to deal with it this way:

```
declare
    myset    varchar := '';

...

loop
    if [condition] then
        myset || ',' || id;
    end if;
    return next resulter;
end loop;

execute 'select sum([field]) from anothertable where id in (' || trim(leading ',' from myset) || ')' into myvar
```

However this doesn't seem too efficient to me when the number of id's to be added to this set is large.  What other options do I have for keeping track of this set and then using it?

-- update --

Obviously, another option is to create a temporary table and insert ids into it when needed.  Then in the last select statement have a sub-select on that temporary table - like so:

```
create temporary table x (id integer);

loop
    if [condition] then
        insert into x values (id);
    end if;
    return next resulter;
end loop;

select into myvar sum([field]) from anothertable where id in (select id from x);
```

Any other options? Also, what would be the most efficient, considering that there may be many thousands of relevant ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, temp tables are the most efficient way to handle this:

```
create temp table x(id integer not null primary key) on commit drop;
```

Comment: I have gone for the temp table at end.  Thanks.